# Why are my sprite sheet's frames not visible in Cocos Builder?

Tags: cocos2d, spritesheet

I have created a sprite sheet with [zwoptex](http://www.zwopple.com/zwoptex). Then I just dragged the `.plist` and `.png` files to my Cocos Builder project. After this I wanted to take a sprite frame and set it to a sprite:

[image]

But the sprite image is empty! At first I thought it was just empty in Cocos Builder, and that it must have been working correctly when imported to a project. But if I try to run that scene with *CCBReader* I still see an empty sprite. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plist file was invalid because I renamed the image, so that the name contained in the plist file wasn't the true one. So I just made the spritesheet again with zwoptex and now everything works fine.